# Can't login to new user

Tags: windows-8.1, login, users

I have Windows 8.1 and I have created a new user by Computer Management. I have created a regular user with some password. But when I tries to login with my new user first time, I got error message

> The User Profile Service service failed the logon. User profile cannot be loaded.`

I saw many solutions to fix the profile, but my user is a new one, it have no profile files yet.

What can I do?

Comment: Did you try to simply remove the user and create it again?

Comment: Yes of course, the error still exists.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was `.sqm` files in the `C:\Users\Default` directory. Just need to search and delete all these files.

Answer (score 0):

Try that one....try to login administrator account and do following steps...

1. Press W8K + R, type following in the Run dialog box and hit Enter:

[image]

2.In the Default folder, from the upper ribbon, choose Share -> Advanced security.

[image]

3. In the Advanced Security Settings for Default window, click Add.

[image]

4. Now, into the Permission Entry for Default window, firstly click Select a principal, then input users in Select User or Group and click Check Names.

[image]

5. Moving on, click OK here:

[image]

6. In this way you have added the new user which was experiencing trouble into the Default users entry. Click Apply followed by OK.

[image]

7. You may get this security warning after clicking OK in above shown window, click Continue repeatedly until its done.

[image]

Now try to logon using the newly created user account, it should work fine.

That’s it!

Comment: Thanks for the guide, but it didn't help. The error still occurred. :(

Comment: Are you sure error occurred failed to log on or signup?

Comment: The new user is active, when I sign out from my original user, I can choose who I login with. When I choose my original user its all works fine. But when I try to login with the new user, I got that error.